# How can .val return a localtime value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the val [docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/) written this description:

> .val() Returns: String, Number, Array

I tried to get a Time, but it seems to return string only, Is there any method to parse the val value to localtime?

```
$.get(href,function(exam,status){
            $('#startTimeEdit').val(exam.startTime);
            $('#endTimeEdit').val(exam.endTime);
        });
```

Overall, my question will be how to parse the val value to LocalTime datatype?

Comment: Are `startTimeEdit` and `endTimeEdit` inputs? HTML inputs always store the values as strings, so you'll need to create a date object from those strings if you need an actual time value.

Comment: `startTimeEdit` and `endTimeEdit` is the input=time which accept the time as value? From your suggestion, is it i need create `Date d = new date` like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're given a stringified date + time in these values, then this will work:

```
$.get(href, (exam, status) => {
    const start = new Date($('#startTimeEdit').val(exam.startTime)).toLocaleTimeString()
    const end = new Date($('#endTimeEdit').val(exam.endTime)).toLocaleTimeString()
    return { start, end }

});
```